# JavaScript how to make forEach loop synchronous

Tags: javascript, node.js, zip

on my project I need to unzip a file and upload its content to a nodeJS server. I am able to unzip the file, e.g. I get the filenames of the content etc.
After unzipping I want to upload the content to my server. This is where the problem is. I am using formData to transmit the file. But every time I try to upload the files it shows me following error on the console in firefox:

"TypeError: Argument 2 of FormData.append does not implement interface Blob."

So it seems that there is no file-object given to the formData...
For unzipping I use JSZip [link to JSZip][1]

**EDIT**

I figured the first problem out myself. Now I am having trouble executing the code in the right order. My JS Code:

```
$("#file").on("change", function (evt) {
    var formData = new FormData();
    var counter = 0;
    // remove content
    $result.html("");
    // be sure to show the results
    $("#result_block").removeClass("hidden").addClass("show");
    // Closure to capture the file information.

    console.log('1');
    function handleFile(f) {
        var $fileContent = $("<ul>");
        $result.append($fileContent);           
            JSZip.loadAsync(f)
                .then(function (zip) {
                    zip.forEach(function (relativePath, zipEntry) {
                        console.log('2');                        
                        console.log(zipEntry);
                        zip.file(zipEntry.name).async("blob").then(function (u8) {
                            console.log('3');  
                            console.log(u8);
                            formData.append('photo', u8, counter);
                            counter++;
                            $fileContent.append($("<li>", {
                                text: zipEntry.name
                            }));
                        })                         
                    });
                }, function (e) {
                    $result.append($("<div>", {
                        "class": "alert alert-danger",
                        text: "Error reading " + f.name + ": " + e.message
                    }));
                });
        }           


    var files = evt.target.files;
    handleFile(files[0]);
});
```

The console output is:

```
1
2
object
2
object
3
blob
3
blob
```

But what I want is:

```
1
2
object
3
blob
2
object
3
blob
```

But i dont know how to put another .then to make this work the way I want to

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to upload a single zip file to node server and then unzip it on the server, validate or filter etc?

Comment: If the zip file is ver large (1GB) then it would take a long time to send it to the server. In case there are unwanted files inside the zip (e.g. wrong data format etc) then it would be inconvenient to send the zip first and then validate on the server.

Comment: On the reverse side if the zip file is going to be large i will mean the files in it will be large or amount of file will be large . In both cases you may face performance issues if you make continues API calls for say 1000 files each of 10 mb in size suppose. Anyway I guess this is another topic in itself